# Is special treatment required for <tag2> within <tag1> in Python's re.sub?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, xml-parsing

Example:

This has desired effect:

Replace the following with blank:

```
<tag condition="MyCondition">Text</tag>
```

Via:

```
string = re.sub('<tag condition=\"MyCondition\">.+</tag>', '', string)
```

But consider the following:

```
<tag2 condition="myCondition2">
<tag>Text</tag> and <tag>text</tag> is here.
</tag2>
```

And that I want to replace `tag2` and all contents with blank eg:

```
string = re.sub('<tag2 condition=\"myCondition2\">.+</tag2>', '', string)
```

It is not removing `tag2` and contents and I think it might be because there are `<tags>` within `tag2`.

How do I replace `tag2` and all contents with blank?

Comment: I was aware of the infamous post on so about not parsing html with regex (and have used Beautiful Soup for more complex parsing), but I thought for these simple, `'find and replace everything with blank'` type of operations, it would be ok to use regex?

Comment: For one tag, it'll work. For one tag with a lot of contents that don't include the closing tag, sure. For anything more complicated, don't even try it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get past simple cases, regex becomes your enemy. Just parse the XML with a proper XML parser, modify the parsed tree, and print it back out:

```
import lxml.etree

xml = '''
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <root>
        <tag condition="MyCondition">Text</tag>

        <tag3>Don't touch me</tag3>

        <tag2 condition="myCondition2">
            <tag>Text</tag> and <tag>text</tag> is here.
        </tag2>
    </root>
'''

tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml.strip())

for element in tree.xpath('//tag[@condition="MyCondition"] | //tag2[@condition="myCondition2"]'):
    element.getparent().remove(element)

print(lxml.etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `re.DOTALL` flag. Without it, your regular expression fails to match the newlines. `tag2` would be fine, as you can see when you try to apply your expression to the (almost) equivalent

```
<tag2 condition="myCondition2"><tag>Text</tag> and <tag>text</tag> is here.</tag2>
```

Comment: that won't work for multiple tag2..also it wont work for self encloses tags! To summarise you don't use regex to parse html/xml

Comment: @Anirudh: Oh, I completely agree. The answer is an explanation of why this doesn't work in this particular case. And OP is "aware of the infamous post".